# Как перезаписать массив с корзиной?

Tags: javascript, php, массивы, ajax

Делаю корзину, из массива получаю значения id, цену, количество, тип товара и название.

Верстка самой корзины выглядит примерно так:

```js
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {
 
        var qty = $(this).parent().find( 'input' ),
            val = parseInt( qty.val() ),
            min = parseInt( qty.attr( 'min' ) ),
            max = parseInt( qty.attr( 'max' ) ),
            step = parseInt( qty.attr( 'step' ) );

        // дальше меняем значение количества в зависимости от нажатия кнопки
        if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
            if ( max && ( max <= val ) ) {
                qty.val( max );
            } else {
                qty.val( val + step );
            }
        } else {
            if ( min && ( min >= val ) ) {
                qty.val( min );
            } else if ( val > 1 ) {
                qty.val( val - step );
            }
        }

        });
```

```css
.text-success{
  color: #68A4C4!important; 
}

.name_value{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  font-weight: 700;

}
.spisok_value{ 

}
.position{ 
  display: flex;
  width: 20%; 
  justify-content: center;
}

.id_position{
  width: 90%; 
  display: flex;        
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.input-cart-form {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=" ">
                            <div class=" ">  
                                <h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 0 0 25px;">Корзина</h1>  
                            </div> 
                            <div class="name_value"> 
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>Название</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>Количество</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>Цена</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>Сумма</p> 
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="spisok_value">    
                                <div class="id_position" id="50">  
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <p>Композиция Нептун</p>
                                            </div>                    
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <div class="input-number">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
                                                    <input class="qty" type="number" value="2" id="50" min="1" max="50" step="1">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="2000">  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="4000">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><div class="id_position" id="49">  
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <p>Букет Уран</p>
                                            </div>                    
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <div class="input-number">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
                                                    <input class="qty" type="number" value="1" id="49" min="1" max="50" step="1">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="2000">  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="2000">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><div class="id_position" id="46">  
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <p>Композиция Космический</p>
                                            </div>                    
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <div class="input-number">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
                                                    <input class="qty" type="number" value="5" id="46" min="1" max="50" step="1">
                                                    <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="5000">  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="position">
                                                <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="25000">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                          </div> 
                            <div class="name_value"> 
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>Итого</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>
                                    8   
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p> </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <p>31000</p> 
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                    
                        </div>
```

Добавил кнопки изменения количества товара, количество меняется, но как записаться новое значение кол-ва в массив, именно перезаписать только значение с количеством для конкретного товара. Массив выглядит вот так:
Array (
[50] => Array ( [bouquet] => Композиция [id] => 50 [name] => Нептун [kol] => 2 [price] => 2000 )
[49] => Array ( [bouquet] => Букет [id] => 49 [name] => Уран [kol] => 1 [price] => 2000 )
[46] => Array ( [bouquet] => Композиция [id] => 46 [name] => Космический [kol] => 5 [price] => 5000 ) )

Пытался отправить данные по аналогии с тем как товар добавляется в корзину ничего не удалось, даже ошибка не вылезла:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '[name="update_cart"]', function() {
     

        var kol = document.getElementById('qty').value; //Получаем количество из поле ввода
        var id = document.getElementById('.id_position').id; //Получаем ID товара 
        
        var formData = new FormData(); //Создадим объект для передачи данных
        formData.append('id', id); //Добавим переменную с ID товара             
        formData.append('kol', kol); //Добавим переменную с количеством товаров 
        
        //ajax
        var HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Создадим объект для отправки AJAX запроса
        HttpRequest.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status == 200) { //Проверка что результат отчета успешный (может быть 404 или другие)
                 
                alert('Успешно обновлен'); 
                 
                document.getElementById('chart-value').innerText = this.response; //Записываем цифру в элемент корзины в верстке
            } else {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
        }; //Функция в которую возвращается ответ от сеовера
        HttpRequest.open("POST", '/cart/', true); //Настройка запроса для отправки (второй параметр путь к PHP скрипту)
        HttpRequest.send(formData); //Отправка запроса на сервер


    } );
```

Саму страницу с товаром сгенерировал вот так:

```
<div class="spisok_value">    
                            <?
                            $mass = $_SESSION['BX_CART']['ids'];            
                            foreach ($mass as $value) { 
                                $summ = $value[price]*$value[kol];
                                $nametype = $value[bouquet] . " " . $value[name];        
                                echo (
                                    
                                    "<div class='id_position' id='$value[id]'>  
                                        <div class='position'>
                                            <p>$nametype</p>
                                        </div>                    
                                        <div class='position'>
                                            <div class='input-number'>
                                                <button type='button' onclick='stepDown()' class='input-cart-form input-number-down minus' >-</button>
                                                <input  class='qty' type='number' value='$value[kol]' id='$value[id]' min='1' max='50' step='1'>
                                                <button type='button' onclick='steUp()' class='input-number-up  plus'>+</button>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='position'>
                                            <input id='price'   class='input-cart-form' value='$value[price]'>   
                                        </div>
                                        <div   class='position'>
                                            <input class='input-cart-form' id='summ-cart' value='$summ'>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>"   
                                );
                            };?>
                        </div>
```

И возможно ли как ни будь сделать это все дело без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: у тебя вообще нет элементов с id = qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у тебя нет никаких элементов с id = qty, поэтому ты не можешь извлечь никакие данные с помощью конструкции `var kol = document.getElementById('qty').value;`.

Во-вторых, так ты извлекаешь одну пару значений `id-количество`, а у тебя может быть несколько таких пар значений (несколько товаров).

Проще взять все данные формы автоматически. Для этого добавляется html-тег `<form>` вокруг твоих полей ввода, полям ввода добавляется атрибут `name`, как я сделал выше `<input name="product-id49">`. Тогда все данные, введенные в именованные поля ввода, подхватятся автоматически с помощью конструкции [new Formdata()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

```
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("form");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
```

Далее отправляешь этот массив на сервер.

Метод [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), которым ты пользовался, позволяет добавлять данные вручную, но тогда придется использовать цикл, чтобы последовательно извлекать данные из полей ввода и вносить их в объект `formData`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="">
  <div class=" ">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 0 0 25px;">Корзина</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="name_value">
    <div class="position">
      <p>Название</p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p>Количество</p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p>Цена</p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p>Сумма</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spisok_value">
    <form name="form">
      <div class="id_position" id="50">
        <div class="position">
          <p>Композиция Нептун</p>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <div class="input-number">
            <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
            <input class="qty" type="number" value="2" id="50" name="product-id50" min="1" max="50" step="1">
            <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="2000">
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="4000">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="id_position" id="49">
        <div class="position">
          <p>Букет Уран</p>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <div class="input-number">
            <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
            <input class="qty" type="number" value="1" id="49" name="product-id49" min="1" max="50" step="1">
            <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="2000">
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="2000">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="id_position" id="46">
        <div class="position">
          <p>Композиция Космический</p>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <div class="input-number">
            <button type="button" class="input-cart-form input-number-down minus">-</button>
            <input class="qty" type="number" value="5" id="46" name="product-id46" min="1" max="50" step="1">
            <button type="button" class="input-number-up  plus">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input id="price" class="input-cart-form" value="5000">
        </div>
        <div class="position">
          <input class="input-cart-form" id="summ-cart" value="25000">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="name_value">
    <div class="position">
      <p>Итого</p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p>
        8
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      <p>31000</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<input type="button" name="update_cart" value="апдейт корзины"></input>

<script>
  $('body').on('click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {

    var qty = $(this).parent().find('input'),
      val = parseInt(qty.val()),
      min = parseInt(qty.attr('min')),
      max = parseInt(qty.attr('max')),
      step = parseInt(qty.attr('step'));

    // дальше меняем значение количества в зависимости от нажатия кнопки
    if ($(this).is('.plus')) {
      if (max && (max <= val)) {
        qty.val(max);
      } else {
        qty.val(val + step);
      }
    } else {
      if (min && (min >= val)) {
        qty.val(min);
      } else if (val > 1) {
        qty.val(val - step);
      }
    }

  });

  $('body').on('click', '[name="update_cart"]', function() {

    //взять данные из формы
    //var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("form");
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    //проверить в консоли
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }

    //ajax
    //Создадим объект для отправки AJAX запроса
    var HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Функция в которую возвращается ответ от сеовера
    HttpRequest.onload = function(e) {
      //Проверка что результат отчета успешный (может быть 404 или другие)
      if (this.status == 200) {
        alert('Успешно обновлен');
        //Записываем цифру в элемент корзины в верстке
        document.getElementById('chart-value').innerText = this.response;
      } else {
        alert('Ошибка');
      }
    };
    //Настройка запроса для отправки (второй параметр путь к PHP скрипту)
    HttpRequest.open("POST", '/cart/', true);
    //Отправка запроса на сервер
    HttpRequest.send(formData);


  });
</script>
```

Comment: Точно, qty это ведь класс а не id, походу нужно передых сделать. Благодарю! Буду пробовать

Comment: Еще вопрос, а как мне поймать эти переданные данные в самом файле где обрабатывается логика корзины?  до этого, когда сам назначал методом  append() получал так $id = $_POST['id']; $name = $_POST['name']; и т.д. и из них уже составлял свой массив, из которого в корзину и тянулись данные. А сейчас получается что отправка идет, но я незнаю как мне эти данные идентифицировать, а мне получается из них теперь нужно будет вытянуть и добавить в мой моссив id (что бы знать в какой конкретно массив добавлять) и новое значение количества (что бы знать что добавлять).

Comment: @Егор var_dump($_POST)